# Implicit Euler method for integration of ODEs

Tags: numerical-methods, ode, newtons-method, numerical-stability

For those of you familiar with the method, it is known that one must solve the equation:

```
y(i+1) = y(i) + h*F( X(i+1), Y(i+1) )
```

However, F is usually not linear, and the resulting equation usually has many different solutions for y(i+1). Which solution are we looking for, and what would one do, for instance, to the Newton-Raphson method so it finds the CORRECT zero? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `Which solution are we looking` depends on the initial values of the system. Initial values play a central rule in solving ODEs. Check out this book http://www.amazon.ca/Numerical-Methods-Engineers-Steven-Chapra/dp/0073401064

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you chose the solution that is closest to `y(i)`. The correct solution should satisfy

```
y(i+1)=y(i)+h*f(x(i),y(i)) + O(h²)
```

However, for stiff problems the constant in `O(h²)` can be very large so that this relation is not as helpful as it seems.

If `L` is the Lipschitz constant of `f` and `q=L·h < 1` then the iteration

```
k(j+1) = f(x(i+1), y(i)+h*k(j))
```

converges geometrically with error proportional to `q^j/(1-q)` or smaller.

This is violated for stiff problems, where you use the Jacobian `J` of `f` in `(x(i+1),y(i))` to iterate

```
k(j+1) = k(j) - (I-h*J)^(-1)*( k(j)-f( x(i+1), y(i)+h*k(j)) )
```

possibly approximating `(I-h*J)^(-1)` as `I+h*J`, see Rosenbrock method. Starting with `k(0)=0` or `k(0)=f(x(i),y(i))` should almost always rapidly converge to the correct solution.